# How to code Visual basic for-loop step increment?

Tags: vb.net, loops, operators, selection, increment

I can't get my project work. I need to show a working schedule who has to work every 3rd weekend with start from week number 1. Assume that the last week of the year is 52.

The program should show like this:

```
     Week 1         Week 4         Week 7
     Week 10        Week 13        Week 16
     Week 19        Week 22        Week 25
     Week 28        Week 31        Week 34
     Week 37        Week 40        Week 43
     Week 46        Week 49        Week 52
```

But my program shown only Week 4

This is my code. How I should fix this?

```
If choice = 1 Then

        Dim colCount As Integer = 0
        Dim weekCounterStart As Integer = 1
        Dim increment As Integer = 3
        Dim maxWeekCounter As Integer = 52
        Dim weekCounter As Integer



        For weekCounter = weekCounterStart To maxWeekCounter Step increment

            weekCounter = weekCounter + increment
            Console.Write(vbTab & "Week " & weekCounter & Environment.NewLine)
            Exit For

            'If it is three columns, write a new line.
            If (colCount >= 2) Then

                colCount = 0
                Console.WriteLine()

            Else
                colCount = +1
            End If


        Next weekCounter
```

Comment: Just to add to Tim answer. Remove the Environment.NewLine and change "colCount = +1" to "colCount += 1" the program will work like expected.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you increment the counter in the first line of the loop body? That is done already by the loop itself. So simply remove it:

```
For weekCounter = weekCounterStart To maxWeekCounter Step increment
    ' weekCounter = weekCounter + increment 'REMOVE!!!
    Console.Write(vbTab & "Week " & weekCounter & Environment.NewLine)
    ' Exit For  'REMOVE!!!
```

You are also exiting the loop immediately, so also remove `Exit For`.

Comment: Aha Thank you. Now it's working as it supposted to be.